# How to execute a template in golang?

Tags: go, execution

I want to execute the home template in the `Login()` function **because I want to add struct values to the HTML file** but I have three problems with this code.

1. The `Login()` redirects to `/` and store the cookie also but it does not execute the `HomeTmpl` and give me an error.  `index.html:217:54: executing "body" at <index .ProductsList 18>: error calling index: index of untyped nil`
2. If I change the `<form action="/">` then it gives me `gomail: invalid address "": mail: no address`.
3. If I remove the `Newsletter(w, r)` from the `Home()` function then it executes the template but doesn't send the cookie.

**Login**

```
func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        return LoginTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    }
    user := models.User{
        Email:    r.FormValue("email"),
        Password: r.FormValue("password"),
    }

    _, match := database.FindAccount(user.Email, user.Password)
    if match {
        tokenString, ok := IsAuthorized(w, r, time.Now().Add(5*time.Minute))
        if ok {
            database.RedisSet("id1", tokenString)
            return HomeTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
            // http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
            // return nil
        } else {Back to Login}
    } else {Back to Login}
}
```

**Home**

```
type ProductStruct struct {
    ProductsList []string
    Description  string
    Link         []string
    ProductsLink []string
    LoggedIn     bool
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        return PageError(w, r)
    }
    var user ProductStruct
    for i := 0; i < 35; i++ {
        user.ProductsList = append(user.ProductsList, products.AccessAnotherData(i))
    }
    var p *ProductStruct // I updated this
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        match := database.RedisGet("id1")
        if match {
            RefreshToken(w, r)
            return HomeTmpl.Execute(w, p)  // I updated this
        } else {
            return HomeTmpl.Execute(w, p)  // I updated this
        }
    } else if r.Method == "POST" {
        Newsletter(w, r)
        return HomeTmpl.Execute(w, p)   // I updated this
    }
    return nil
}
```

**login.html**

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: I think you should use value of pointer to send values e.g `user := new (ProductStruct)` or `user := &ProductStruct{}` . Your `Execute` method should be `Execute(w http.ResponseWriter, p *ProductStruct)`

Comment: @Jibon I did it like this `var p *ProductStruct, return HomeTmpl.Execute(w, p)` but it is giving me this error. `<.ProductsList>: nil pointer evaluating *controllers.ProductStruct.ProductsList`

Comment: @Jibon I have given the `ProductStruct` in the above code also. You can see it.

Comment: Is there anyone to answer my question?

Comment: Please edit your question to add `Execute` method that you've implemented. Something is wrong there. Also update the code that you've tried.

Comment: You can read more about pointers from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-golang/

Comment: @Jibon I updated the code but this time it gave me this error. `executing "body" at <.ProductsList>: nil pointer evaluating *controllers.ProductStruct.ProductsList`